# Trying to locate an element in a webpage but getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to get the webdriver to click a button on the site [random.org](https://www.random.org/) The button is a generator that generates a random integer between 1 and 100. It looks like this:

[image: The generator button]

After inspecting the webpage, I found the corresponding element on the webpage looks something like this:

[image: The HTML skeleton]

It is inside an iframe and someone suggested that I should first switch over to that iframe to locate the element, so I incorporated that in my code but I am constantly getting `NoSuchElementException` error. I have attached my code and the error measage below for your reference. I can't understand why it cannot locate the button element despite referencing the ID, which is supposed to unique in the entire document.

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get("https://www.random.org/")

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))

button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='hnbzsqjufzxezy-button']")

button.click()
```

The error message:

[image: The error message]

Comment: The iframe has a src attribute, why don't you try scraping that site instead
Also You can make the css selector more reliable by using input[type=button][value='Generate'] or something of the lieks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that there are no more Iframes on the page. If there are a few an not only one do this:

```
iframes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS, 'iframe')
// try switching to each iframe:
driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])
driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[1])
```

You can't find the button because its name contain random letters. Every time you will refresh the page you can see that the name value will change. So, do this:

```
button = driver.findElement(By.CSS, 'input[type="button"][value="Generate"]')
button.click()
```

Comment: I have checked the document, it was the only iframe, but now that you mention it, the ID indeed changes after every refresh. I should have refreshed the page a couple of times, although i did not anticipate that webpages can have dynamic IDs. Thanks, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. First you need to close the cookies banner
2. The locator of the button is wrong. It's id is dynamic.
3. You need to use `WebDriverWait` to wait for elements clickability.
   The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = 'https://www.random.org/'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick*='all']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id*='button']"))).click()
```

Comment: Do cookie banners interfere with functions of other elements? I was able to interact with elements on some other webpages without closing them, but I guess I should have done so. But the real problem seems to be the dynamic ID that you mention. I am new to the selenium library, so a lot of the functionalities that you used are new to me. It seems like a significantly more robust code, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sometimes cookies banners may be leaved, but in most cases it's better to close them. In case this resolved your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers